# Use of eval with div

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I am new to asp.net and I wanted to know that is it possible to create any number of div dynamically with the use of "eval" if yes, then how?
I guess somehow like this

`<div id=<%# Eval("UnitName") %>>`

Comment: You missed the quotes around the `<%# %>`. But easier than that, why not just `<div id='UnitName'>`.

Comment: number of divs will be decided at run time. Exact number of div to be created will depend on the data retrieved at run time from database

Comment: be more specific about your requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it. But you need to make sure not to use multiple `div` with same `id`, which is `UnitName` in your case. If you will use same `UnitName` with multiple `div` elements it will generate error. It must be unique.

```
<div id='<%# Eval("UnitName") %>'>
```

> Element IDs should be unique within the entire document.